# Создать свою форму в QGraphics

Tags: c++, qt

Можно ли используя QGraphicsItem-ы создать к примеру тело человека? То есть скрепить элементы например QGraphicsRectItem вместе и создать тело.

Comment: Тебя ничего не ограничивает, можешь хоть каждую клетку тела так сделать. ГрафикАйтем может быть что угодно, а вот как скреплять лучше подсказать не могу.

Comment: Я имею ввиду чтобы каждый раз не мучится с кодом и сразу прорисовывать тело при помощи уже созданного класса к примеру

Comment: Что мешает сделать базовый класс PartBodyClass и от него наследовать HandClass, и т.д.? а в Нэде ты можешь написать PartBodyClass::любой public/protected метод родительского класса. Погуглите примеры наследования, там есть нужные вам ответы на вопросы.